# How to change number of entries in two jQuery dataTables with one html select box?

Tags: jquery, datatable

Is there a way to show the selected number of entries on all datatables in a page and not just individually?

Here is the individual dataTable:

```
var stockTable = $('#source').dataTable({
    "aaData": src,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bRedraw":true,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "bInfo":true,
    "bLengthChange":true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {"mData": "Title"},
        {"mData": "ID"},
        {"mData": "Language"}]
});

var catalogTable = $('#destination').dataTable({
    "aaData": dest,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bRedraw":true,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "bInfo":true,
    "bLengthChange":true,

    "aoColumns": [

        {"mData": "Module Title"},
        {"mData": "Module ID"},
        {"mData": "Module Language"}
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable" : "<h1>Drag and Drop Courses Here</h1>"
}
});
```

If there is another similar datatable and I have a selectbox as follows:

```
<div class="filterArea borderBottomMedium clearfix">
<div class="no_padding entriesLength">
    <label>Show</label>
    <select id="entries" class="form-control">
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
      <option>30</option>
      <option>40</option>
      <option>50</option>
    </select>
    <label>entries</label>
</div>
```

Can I use the selection to show the number of entries in all the dataTables?bLengthChange is true and I can change both tables individually.but how can I change both of them together to the number of entries selected in selectbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a separate drop down from the "Show N entries" datatables dropdown, you'll need to tie a change event to your drop down, which then changes the dropdowns in the datatables.  The drop downs on the datatables have a name that starts with the same id as your datatables.  So, for example, if your datatable has id="example", the "Show N entries" name starts with "example".

You can either give your tables id's that all start with the same word (like my example), or you can use multiple name selectors in your JQuery binding.

You'll want to make sure your tables all have the same drop down values as your independent drop down.  You can do that with the lengthMenu option:

```
$('.table').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -1], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, "All"]]
} );
```

You can then tie your independent drop down to a change event, and then select the same value from each datatable's dropdown (and trigger a change event so the newly selected number of rows event occurs)

```
$("#entries").on('change',function() {
   var valSelected = $(this).val();
   $("select[name^='example']").each(function(i, val) {
       $(this).val(valSelected);
       $(this).change();
   });
});
```

Please see this fiddle for a full working example:  **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1eqqqwym/1/) example**

Comment: I have uploaded the entire code. Is there a way to do this with dataTables?

Comment: can you show how are the dropdowns related to the datatables?

Comment: nevermind.  i think i understand what you're trying to do now.  i'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Right now the dropdown is not related to the dataTables.I need to use this dropdown for both datatables.

Comment: You'll want to make sure you define lengthMenu with the same values as your external selectbox.  See the JSFiddle example I posted in my answer.  No other settings are needed.

Comment: It's actually working with "bLengthChange":true, which also gives individual select boxes.But I don't need the individual boxes?

Comment: Technically, you need the individual boxes because those are what control the number of rows in each datatable.  Your external selectbox should change those individual selectboxes.  However, you may be able to HIDE those individual selectboxes so they are not visible.  I'm not sure if that will prevent them from working.

Comment: You'll keep bLengthChange : true, but hide the selectboxes (maybe with bInfo ?)

Comment: bInfo:false does not solve it.However,  $('.dataTables_length').hide(); does the trick.Thank you.